# Maven declare version range, avoid unnecessary libraries

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I'm trying avoid following situation:

I have library `A` which depends on library `B` in version `1.1`. Next I create new project where I depend on `A` and `C` which depends on library `B` in version `2.0`. From what I understand I will have two libraries `B` in different versions. But what if actually `A` can also depends on `B` in version `2.0`, so actually only one lib is needed? It would be nice if I could define that `A` works with certain interval, in this case: `<1.1 - 2.0>`.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify range in version something like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>[3.0, 3.8.2)</version>
</dependency>
```

but prior to build you would have to invoke

```
mvn versions:resolve-ranges
```

to resolve to actual version number

---

- [Reference](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/resolve-ranges.html)

Comment: Why would you have to run "resolve ranges"? Would Maven not automatically process this?

Comment: Last question I haven't mention. What would happen if I have two ranges like `[1.2, 2.0]` and `[1.5, 1.7]` and there are libraries in repository `1.5`, `1.6`, `1.7` which one would be chosen? Oldest, newest or random?

Comment: Try it see in the log with -X flag